# Mysql command CASE Compare with sub query

Tags: mysql

I have a sql command which I parse to a custom pdo function. The command works perfectly.

```
SELECT table1.* FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table2.col1 = table1.col3
WHERE table1.col4 = 'myVal'
AND 2016-10-01 > (
SELECT MAX(loginDate) FROM table4 WHERE table4.id = table1.id
)
```

The problem I have is that the value in my example `2016-10-01` is depenadnt on a column value. for example if table1.col7 = 'foo' then I want the comparison value to be `2016-10-01`. If table1.col7 = 'bar' I want the comparison value to be `2016-09-01`. If table1.col7 = 'test' I want the comparison value to be `2016-08-01`. Else I want the comparison value to be `2016-07-01`.

any Ideas on how I implement this kind of conditioning in mysql?

Comment: Where you are using `php`,`mysqli` and `pdo`?

Comment: @RamaLingam my question could apply to either. It's generic sql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `CASE` to produce the required date value:

```sql
SELECT table1.* 
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table2.col1 = table1.col3
WHERE table1.col4 = 'myVal' AND 
      CASE table1.col7 
         WHEN 'foo' THEN '2016-10-01'
         WHEN 'bar' THEN '2016-09-01'
         WHEN 'test' THEN '2016-08-01'
         ELSE '2016-07-01' 
      END
      > 
      (SELECT MAX(loginDate) FROM table4 WHERE table4.id = table1.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the condition to this format:

```
AND CASE WHEN table1.col7 = 'foo' THEN '2016-10-01'
         WHEN table1.col7 = 'bar' THEN '2016-09-01'
         .... END > (SELECT... )
```